# ¿Como obtener la semana anterior PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo las siguientes variables:

```
 $semana                 = $_POST['semana'];
 list($part1, $part2)    = explode('_', $semana);
 $fecha_7_dias           = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($part1."+ 6 days"));
```

**$semana:** 07-01-2019_02-2019

**$part1:** 07-01-2019

**$fecha_7_dias:** 13-01-2019

**$part2:** 02-2019

Obtengo la fecha desde el lunes hasta el domingo de la semana **"02-2019"** pero ahora necesito mostrar las fechas de la semana anterior **"01-2019"** que vendría siendo entre **31-12-2018** al **06-01-2019**

Comment: Juan tu pregunta no es clara. Explica qué es lo que quieres en sí: -¿Dada una fecha obtener la fecha 7 días atrás con respecto a esa fecha? -¿Obtener el número de semana en que cae esa fecha? -¿Obtener el número de semana de la semana anterior a esa fecha? -¿Obtener los días de la semana anterior a esa fecha? Leyendo las preguntas y las respuestas se puede llegar a todas esas conclusiones. Creo que sería bueno que digas con claridad lo que quieres, poniendo algún ejemplo con datos reales y explicando al mismo tiempo cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creas la variable de esta forma:

```
// fechadeseada = formato Y-m-d o date('Y-m-d') en caso de que quieras coger la de ahora
$fecha = new \DateTime(fechadeseada);
$fecha = $fecha->modify('-1 week');
```

y luego esa fecha la puedes poner en el formato que quieras:

```
$fecha->format('Y-m-d');
```

Y ya tienes la fecha de una semana antes.

Comment: Pero tambien necesito tener el año, osea tendria que imprimir "01-2019"

Comment: El problema que tengo tambien es cuando consulto de la semana "01-2019" y traerme la semana 52 porque esa semana es desde el "31-12-2018" al "06-01-2019"

Comment: he actualizado, mira si te sirve eso. No acabo de comprender que es exactamente lo que buscas

Comment: Quiero a la semana concatenar el año en que se encuentra esa semana